# Not all java threads start

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee

I have huge amount of records in oracle database that some operations souhld be done for them.
The application gets 4 parameters as input. They are "Range from", "Range to", "Thread counts" and "blockSize".
By using this parameters, the application calculates how many records should be assigned to every thread.
When a thread starts, it fetches records from databasee blockSize by blockSize and does some operations and then, saves records to another table of databse.
I tested the application with 10,000 records in a machine with 8 cpus and set Number of threads to 8. There is no problem.
In real environment, there are 1,000,000 records and 16 cpus. By running the application there, and setting thread counts to 16 or 12, 
some threads don't start. There is no error or exception message. They just never
 don't run. Other threads start successfully. any idea?

Below is part of the code prepares threads :

```java
List list = new ArrayList();
Object[] records;

int allIDsSize = to - from + 1;

int segmentSize = Math.round(allIDsSize % threadsCount == 0 ? allIDsSize / threadsCount : allIDsSize / threadsCount + 1);

Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(0);

List<Future> threads = new ArrayList<Future>();
int k = 0;
while (k * segmentSize < allIDsSize) {
    int from2 = segmentSize * k + 1;

    int to2;
    if (from2 + segmentSize - 1 < allIDsSize) {
        to2 = from2 + segmentSize - 1;
    } else {
        to2 = allIDsSize;
    }

    k++;

    MyThread thread = new MyThread(from + from2 - 1, from + to2 - 1, semaphore); //MyThread implements Callable<String>

    if (log.isInfoEnabled()) {
        log.info(String.format("Thread IDs are from %d to %d", (from + from2 - 1), (from + to2 - 1)));
        log.info("thread started " + k);
    }

    Future<String> future = pool.submit(thread);
    threads.add(future);
}

semaphore.acquire(threads.size());
```

Thanks.

Solmaz.

Comment: What is `pool` and how is it defined?

Comment: Could you add the code of the MyThread constructor?

Comment: Pool is ExecutorService and declared as final and initialized in constructor : 
pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadsCount);

Comment: Entire callable is in a try/catch block.        
in call method :
        try {
  //do some works...
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "";
        }
        finally {
            if (semaphore != null) {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }

Comment: About Semaphore declaration, you are right. I can fix it.

MyThread constructor just initializes properties. Do you want call() method body?

Comment: Are you certain, your threads dont start execution? Could it be, the threads do indeed start but lock up because of some race-condition? For example, joining the threads via semaphore.acquire(threads.size()) looks like an accident waiting to happen. Why don't you use join()?

Comment: @Jonathan and @Sanjay T. Sharma. The Semaphore usage is basically ok, acquire(N) will await the release of N `permits`, signaling that all tasks have executed. However, a `CountDownLatch` is more natural for these use cases. join() would not be correct, since the actual threads are managed by the executor service.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the case that some threads finish before all tasks have been submitted to the executor queue, and consequently that the executor service does not have to create the maximum number of threads (fixed thread pool creates new threads as needed up to the limit, it does not create all threads at once).

As a side note: It is confusing that you use the *thread* concept (`thread` and `MyThread`) for something that is really a *task*, (i.e. `Runnable`or `Callable`).